# How to show ToolTip dynamically via server side code

Tags: asp.net, tooltip

I would like to show an image tooltip dynamically via server side code. 
For example, when user make a selection in a combo box, i would like to load dynamically a text into an image ToolTip, then automatically show (without the user must move curors on image).
Is it possible ?

Thanks